# How to get helper instance on Magento 2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, module, helper

I tested all methods that I found that were reported here all about Magento 2.0, but seems like Magento 2.1 is different, how can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of using the **Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product** helper class by using dependency injection,

```
private $productHelper;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper
){
    $this->productHelper = $productHelper;
}

public function myFunction()
{
    $this->productHelper->doSomething();
}
```